# AudioUnit Output Stream Bluetooth

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to stream my audio (output from AudioUnit callback) to bluetooth audio device.
I found [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html) from Apple doc.
So try this code, but nothing happens:

```
int audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
int audioRoute = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(audioCategory, &audioCategory);
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRoute, &audioRoute);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

related : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841065/playback-through-a-bluetooth-connected-speaker)

Comment: I solve my problem, I should configure my AudioUnit after loading the view...

Comment: hi, could you please post some example here