# how to Send string from iPhone to other Bluetooth Device

Tags: iphone

I am new with BluetoothLE in iPhone. I want to send string via bluetooth from IOS device to other non IOS device. I refer the BTLETransfer Example from the sample code in the developer portal it shows how to transmit data between two iOS devices. I also refer this link [How to tranfer the call from one bluetooth device to other bluetooth device from iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981175/how-to-tranfer-the-call-from-one-bluetooth-device-to-other-bluetooth-device-from) 
but did not find the solution.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

By using BTLETransfer Example from the sample code we can send String for iOS devices but In case of other non OS devices you have to create own advertiser packet containing you string like mentioned in sample code and other non OS devices must be able to read that packet and Other OS device must support BTLE.

In my case other OS device is Android and Android device able to catch packets advertise by iOS device by using BTLETransfer Example sample.

you can check this sample code will help you lot :

https://github.com/KhaosT/CBPeripheralManager-Demo/tree/master/PeripheralModeTest/PeripheralModeTest

Note : Use same CBUUID for other OS devices.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.  I am not geting your point. because my iPad is not connecting with android nexux5. can you help me how can i start?

Comment: First you need to run the above mention sample code using two iOS devices after you know how it is working you need to create a sample code like that for android also.