# What is kAudioSessionProperty_InputSources actually good for?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

I've tried to fetch the list of available audio input devices on an iPhone by using this code:

```
CFArrayRef arrayRef;
UInt32 size = sizeof(arrayRef);
OSStatus status = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_InputSources, &size, &arrayRef);
assert(status == noErr);
NSArray *array = (__bridge NSArray *)arrayRef;
```

The call works and returns without error, but the results array is always empty, no matter what hardware I have connected to it. I've tried two usual headsets for mobiles, an original one from Apple and one from Samsung and two kinds of USB microphones (an [iXY from Rode](http://www.rodemic.com/news/introducing-the-ixy-microphone-and-rode-rec-app-for-iphone-and-ipad) and an [iM2X from Tascam](http://www.tascam.eu/de/im2x.html)), but the array always stays empty. So I wonder what kinds of input sources would actually be listed by this property? Is it usable at all?

By using a listener callback on the audio routes, I was able to verify that all 4 devices are detected correctly. I was also able to record audio with each of the devices, so they all work properly. I use an iPhone 4S with iOS 6.1.3 (10B329).

Answer (score 3):

The property you are referring to is only for audio input sources in a USB audio accessory attached through the **iPad camera connection kit**, as mentioned in the **AudioSessionServices** class reference.

To get an array that is not nil you will need to test with say a USB Audio Workstation that plugs into the **iPad camera connection kit**.

Here is a link that lists some hardware that uses the **iPad camera connection kit**.

[Connecting USB audio interfaces using the Apple iPad Camera Connection Kit.](http://www.noterepeat.com/products/akai-professional/mpd-and-mpk-series/39-connecting-usb-audio-interfaces-midi-controllers-and-keyboards-to-the-ipad)

Also from the class reference

> If there is no audio input source available from the attached accessory, this property’s value is an empty array.

So from the list found in the above link (*scroll down to List of some compatible devices sub heading*), devices you would be interested in, that yield a !nil result, would be some device that offers audio input such as the **Alesis iO4**, **iO2**, or **iO2 express**.

EDIT: there's merit in the answer provided by Shawn Hershey, with regards to using a non-deprecated objective-c alternative. However you would be most interested in the **portType** property of the **AVAudioSessionPortDescription** class. (*available from iOS 6.0*)
Two constants of interest are - **AVAudioSessionPortLineIn** and **AVAudioSessionPortUSBAudio**. The first one mentioned is for audio input through the dock connector, which is the way your test microphones mentioned connect.

In iOS 7.0 and later you can query the **availableInputs** property of the **AVAudioSession** class. In iOS 6 you can only query the **currentRoute** property.

I found this Technical Q&A very helpful -
[AVAudioSession - microphone selection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1799/_index.html)

Comment: Looks like you are right.  "`kAudioSessionProperty_InputSources`" is only for USB-based audio inputs.  That's unfortunate, as there isn't a non-deprecated way to get ***all*** audio inputs via Core Foundation / C functions (that aren't Objective-C specific).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thank you, I agree it is unfortunate, given that the higher level alternatives will carry more overhead.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann and others, can you tell me which Objective-C alternatives are there to get the non-camera-connection-kit input devices? Is it the one mentioned by Shawn Hershey in his answer to this question?

Comment: You win the bounty not because I got the answer I was looking for (which I think Vizllx was on the right track), but because you explained the situation really well. For those developers who need to use AudioClient API's, there currently doesn't appear to be a non-deprecated way ([thinking of `AudioSessionGetProperty` & `kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute` here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375837/how-to-route-iphone-audio-to-the-bluetooth-headset)) to do what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very new to audio programming on iPhones so I don't have an answer to the question of what that particular property is good for, but if you want the list of audio inputs, I think this will work:

```
NSArray * ais = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
```

This provides an array of AVAudioSessionPortDescription objects.

```
for (id object in ais) {
    AVAudioSessionPortDescription * pd = (AVAudioSessionPortDescription*)object;
    NSLog(@"%@",pd.portName);
}
```