# record input coming from bluetooth headset in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I have a project in which I have to record the voice coming from bluetooth headset and play with default iPhone speaker. I have searched a lot and got this code.

```
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;

    AudioSessionSetProperty (
                             kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
                             sizeof (allowBluetoothInput),
                             &allowBluetoothInput
                             );
```

------------ CODE FOR AUDIO RECORDER START AND STOP ------------

```
- (IBAction)Record: (id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if([btn isSelected])
    {
        [audioRecorder stop];
        [btn setSelected:NO];
        [btn setTitle:@"Start Recording" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [audioRecorder record];
        [btn setSelected:YES];
        [btn setTitle:@"Stop Recording" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

and i am using avaudiorecorder after this. There seems to be something else I am missing in here.

-------- Code for audio recorder ---------

```
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:AUDIO_FILE];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:soundFileURL
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    }
```

I think i am missing something else which needs to be added here. I just want the bluetooth headset input audio. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: hello @Swati need to knw about the functionality that you have been done. please comment me when you are online i need to knw about it so please.

Comment: today having hollyday swati so plz comment monday. if u have timd when u getting online

Comment: Okay. You are also in IST zone. I will try to come online tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i just review your issue and got nice answer something you want try with Bellow code:-

```
// create and set up the audio session
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setDelegate:self];
    [audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
    [audioSession setActive: YES error: nil];

    // set up for bluetooth microphone input
    UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
    OSStatus stat = AudioSessionSetProperty (
                             kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
                             sizeof (allowBluetoothInput),
                             &allowBluetoothInput
                            );
    NSLog(@"status = %x", stat);    // problem if this is not zero

    // check the audio route
    UInt32 size = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    CFStringRef route;
    OSStatus result = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &size, &route);
    NSLog(@"route = %@", route);    
    // if bluetooth headset connected, should be "HeadsetBT"
    // if not connected, will be "ReceiverAndMicrophone"

    // now, play a quick sound we put in the bundle (bomb.wav)
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef        soundFileURLRef;
    SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;
    soundFileURLRef  = CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle,CFSTR ("bomb"),CFSTR ("wav"),NULL);

    NSError *error = nil;

    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:soundFileURLRef
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    }
```

Credit goes to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375837/how-to-route-iphone-audio-to-the-bluetooth-headset)

Comment: this really worked. Thanks.. But the audio output when i play the recording also goes to bluetooth device. I want it in device speaker. Can this be done?

Comment: Add this two line and maight be Helps AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef,&soundFileObject);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);

Comment: where exactly should i add these two lines?

Comment: after this soundFileURLRef  = CFBundleCopyResourceURL

Comment: this method of yours did not work for me but i have added the code to change the property to audiospeaker while playing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35417/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-swati)

Comment: @Swati : Can you add your changes here ? So, future visitors can get proper guidance.

Comment: is there any way i can block my dvice mic input?

Comment: hi @Swati check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch

Comment: this link talks about detecting if the speaker is mute or not. I want to block my device mic. So that when a person is speaking through bluetooth, only that sound gets recorded and not the device mic voice.

Comment: swati can i get code to record voice from BT and to paly on device speaker any appriciated.i have same requirement,even i had used the above code but this code not record the voice from BT but it play sound in BT device

Comment: Hey Swati,
I want same thing to do.the audio output when i play the recording also goes to bluetooth device. I want it in device speaker.

Please provide me some solution or code lines.

Thanks

Comment: Should be noted that although certainly correct when posted, AudioSessionSetProperty was deprecated in iOS7. If you're building for iOS7+, you want to instead call AVSession setCategory: withOptions: and pass AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth as the options argument

Answer (score 0):

add the audio session to your code

```
// create and set up the audio session
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setDelegate:self];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: adding this does not play anything when i play

Comment: rest code is same as your code i have just sent you the Audio session

Answer (score 0):

Try out this amazing piece of code. Will work for sure

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth  error:NULL];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:NULL];

NSString *preferredPortType = AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP;
for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *desc in audioSession.availableInputs)
{
    if ([desc.portType isEqualToString: preferredPortType])
    {
        [audioSession setPreferredInput:desc error:nil];
    }
}
```