# ios: how to record from bluetooth headset use audio queue?

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth, queue

I want to analyze the audio stream data,  although I know that AVAudioRecorder can record from bluetooth headset according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226255/record-input-coming-from-bluetooth-headset-in-iphone) but by AVAudioRecorder I cannot get the real time audio data.

I am using the [SpeakHere](https://github.com/ericmash/ios_speakhere) to record which uses audio queue and set session category and property as that answer mentioned in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, but it doesn't work. I would appreciate a lot if anyone give me some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem was that the settings can't be located in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, it should be after the method `AudioSessionInitialize` called.

```
//Enable Bluetooth headset input
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
OSStatus statBluetoothInput = AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
                                                           sizeof (allowBluetoothInput),
                                                           &allowBluetoothInput);

//Enable Speaker output
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
OSStatus statSpeakerOutput = AudioSessionSetProperty (
                                                          kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                                                          sizeof (audioRouteOverride),
                                                          &audioRouteOverride);
```