# Use Audio Unit I/O to create audio on the fly?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-audio, audio-streaming, audiounit

I am doing a POC in which I need to create an app which fetches Input from iPhone mic and outs the output to the Bluetooth headset/speakers.

I referred the following code

http://www.stefanpopp.de/2011/capture-iphone-microphone/

The code works flawlessly but it produces the output via In-Call Speakers.

Can anyone suggest where I should edit the code to re-route the output to Bluetooth Speakers?

Comment: Nice question.Even i am also tried lot of coding and all but none of the r working.But I can record voice using mic and play later with bluetooth speakers.But I want to play simultaneously.

Comment: I have reached to a point where your iPhone would act as a re-router to bluetooth device. You simply click on the bluetooth on button and you can now use the bluetooth mic and speaker of the device. Its an apple compulsion that you need to have bluetooth output for bluetooth input.

Comment: using the sample in the question, i was able to re-route the output to speakers but it was producing a lag and therfore producing a noise along with the output.

Comment: @SURESHSANKE can you please comment your code . same scheme needed for me .