# Play live sound from iOS app to Bluetooth speakers

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audio-recording

I have to build an iOS app for one of my client. The concept is If I blow into the iPhone mic, the sound could be come from the blue tooth speaker. For example If I say "Hi" in the mic, the app should pass that audio to the Bluetooth speaker and sound should comes from the blue tooth speaker. Till now I have done the Bluetooth pairing .  I have been searching for this since last 3 days but couldn't find any solution. Please let me know any suggestions or links to start the app.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. But forget about sound input for a second.  Have you written any code that can play sound?  If so, that sound should output thru the bluetooth speaker. Correct?

Comment: I have written code for playing the audio file (Audio file is in the resource folder of my project) to the blue tooth speaker . But now I want to send the live audio.

Comment: Since the output is simply selectable if there are options, this question has nothing to do with bluetooth. Actually, you want to record and playback at the same time. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184341/ios-sample-code-for-simultaneous-record-and-playback or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215180/record-and-play-audio-simultaneously

Comment: Exactly tis is a valid question.Upto now no one implemented this requirement in iOS app. I have saw one android app matches to this.I have gone through some samples matches to this in iOS but they are playing live sound from device speakers itself but not from bluetooth speakers. here i add the link to that resource plea got through this.If you have solved this already please reply me with help.https://code.google.com/p/ios-coreaudio-example/downloads/list

Comment: @Tendulkar Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the correct audio route. You have to do this by configuring `AVAudioSession`. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357460/1864294) describes quite well how to do this.